# Need some help regarding this Lambda expression in java

Tags: java, dictionary

I came across this statement while going through JSR-335 specifications:

```
(test ? list.map(String::length) : Collections.emptyList())::iterator
```

What does this `list.map(String::length)` mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `map` operation lets you apply a function, in this case, `String::length` to each argument in the list, and returns *another* collection comprised of the results of applying that function to each one of those list elements.  In this case, a list of Integers.

Lets say I have a list that looks like:

```
{"Bob", "Mary", "Joe"}
```

then you'd get back:

```
{3, 4, 3}
```

after applying your particular mapping.

Comment: i came across this link... and found it very useful
http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/java-8-explained-applying-lambdas-to-java-collections/

Answer (score 3):

I believe that's a reference to the `length` methods defined in `java.lang.String`. In this case, you're basically telling `.map()` to call the method on every member of the collection and return a new collection comprised of those lengths.